# Math.Truncate return incorrect decimal cut off

Tags: c#, .net

A weird thing happened when I tried to add 4 decimals (demanded in solution) to a 2-decimal double value:

**Incorrect value:**

```
    var result = string.Format("{0:#,0.0000}", Math.Truncate(2.03*10000)/10000);
```

//Returns 2.0299

**Correct values:**

```
    var result = string.Format("{0:#,0.0000}", Math.Truncate(2.02*10000)/10000);
```

//Returns 2.0200

**And:**

```
    var result = string.Format("{0:#,0.0000}", Math.Truncate(2.04*10000)/10000);
```

//Returns 2.0400

Any idea why this happens ONLY to 2.03? 12.03 as input value returns 12.0300 btw.

I am lost. Please help.

Comment: If you want fixed result, use decimal, not double. double is an approximation.

Comment: There are infinitely many floating point values between any two floating point values, yet we only have 32- or 64-bits to describe them. By definition you cannot describe them all with finite precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point multiplying by 10000 and dividing by 10000 here. You only risk introducing slight errors, like what you see here: note that doubles and floats use a base-2 representation and hence cannot exactly represent arbitrary decimal numbers.

This will give you what you want:

```
String.Format("{0:#,0.0000}", 2.03)
```

If you require perfect accuracy with decimal numbers, use the decimal type instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is loss of precision that under certain circumstannces isn't a big deal. Try using the [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) type like this:

```
var result = string.Format("{0:#,0.0000}", Math.Truncate(2.03m*10000m)/10000m);
```

Answer (score 0):

The number 2.03 is represented as a binary number which means that it cannot be stored exactly. This can lead to rounding errors (say, 15 digits after the decimal point) which are not corrected by Truncate.

You avoid the problem if you round the number.

Comment: This is correct. 2.03 is one of those numbers that simply cannot be represented exactly with a `double`. A quick Google search claims that the closest approximation of `2.03` is `2.02999999999999980460074766597`, which is consistent with the "incorrect" value.

Comment: Your analysis of why it's wrong is correct, your proposed solution is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.... it will help you...

```
        var result = Decimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(2.03 * 10000 / 10000), .0000m);
        //Results 2.0300

        var result = Decimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(2.02 * 10000 / 10000), .0000m);
        //Results 2.0200

        var result = Decimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(2.04 * 10000 / 10000), .0000m);
        //Results 2.0400

        var result = Decimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(12.03 * 10000 / 10000), .0000m);
        //Results 12.0300
```